# Tiny ARM Development Board?

Tags: arm, linux, android, board, development

I need a very small ARM based development board capable of running Linux (and Android, if possible, via SD card). The board should be not more than 25mm in terms of breadth. I found Raspberry Pi Model A to be perfect but it's not available. Any alternatives?

Comment: As worded, this question implies that the other dimensions could be anything at all. "breadth" to  me means the shorter of the two dimensions that is not height. Can it be 600mm long and 300mm tall? Please be a bit more clear.

Comment: This is another shopping question @newelechacker, I want this site to be a great resource for you but shopping questions are not a good fit. Instead ask questions as you run into specific technical issues.

Answer (score 2):

After measuring a Raspberry Pi and looking at claimed dimensions I conclude that your 25mm measurement refers to the "height" or thickness.

A Raspberry Pi model B is slightly less than 25mm thick between extreme projections.
 (4.5mm SD card socket + 1.6mm PCB + 15.6mm dual USB connector = 21.7mm)

The model A may be slightly less, and you can easily reduce Model B height by 2.3mm by fitting a single USB socket or hard wiring to an external socket.
 You can reduce height further by removing the "ethernet" socket and further again by removing the RCA socket. BUT you said <= 25mm so the Raspberry Pi model B should work as is.

Raspberry Pi Model B is available [**On ebay now for from $105 buy now**](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_nkw=raspberry+pi&rt=nc&LH_BIN=1).
 Or I'll send you one of mine tomorrow if your offer is good enough :-). These are scheduled to drop to about $US35 in the next few months.

The Olunuxino ARM board is close to Raspberry Pi and can be had [**on ebay for $63 buy now**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Olimex-iMX233-OLINUXINO-MAXI-linux-computer-ARM926J-alternative-to-Raspberry-Pi-/280895044174?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Components_Supplies_ET&hash=item4166a63a4e)

---

**Raspberry Pi dimensions:**

[From here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4402):

[image]

[Photo below from here](http://tech4tea.com/blog/2012/05/09/)

[image]

You don't state the other dimensions which are critical.
 As you only mention width, and say that RPA (Raspberry Pi model A) mis perfect for your requirement then RPB is also perfect.

Your 25mm breadth (= width) does not make sense as a RP is

~ 85 mm x 56 mm (PCB) or
 ~ 95 mm x 65 mm  (outre dimensions, model B)

Model B is just under 25mm thick or tall from SD socket on one side to top of dual USB connector on the other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another thing to ask: Is there some kind of mini projector based glasses available? Something like Google Glasses? I am thinking to hack together a simple AR glass running Android! Even spare parts will suffice (of the glasses)

Answer (score 2):

Check out Carambola: http://www.8devices.com/product/3/carambola

It's 35x45mm, running OpenWRT. Plus it has WiFi onboard.

They're also developing the same board, but way much smaller. Like 25x35mm or something... It was announced on forum.

Comment: Can't run Android.

Comment: I'd say it can, You'll have to port Android to support that Ralink CPU :-)